# How to extrapolate on a time series based on correlation

Tags: time-series, regression, correlation, extrapolation

I have a time series data for one year (T1). I have another time series data (T2) for 1 month (Jun). I find there are some similarities between two time series in Jun using correlation coefficients. How can I extrapolate (Jan to Dec) the second time series using the first time series.